# Working with classes but can't display the answer.

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I really didn't want to write this question, but I can't seem to be able to output the name. This IS a part of an assignment for my class and it is the hardest part of the assignment, BUT my teacher said that we can get help and ask others, as long as we actually learn and understand what we are doing and why we are doing it. So I'm asking this to help me understand why my program wont output the persons name.

What I'm trying to do is; input a name "lEonArDo DA vINCi" that has UPPER and lower case letters in it, as well as the date they were born "1520", then have code that turns the name into lower case and capitalizes only the first letters in the words, and finally output that name.

What I'm stuck on is outputting the name. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've asked others in my class but they are ether still on the first part or they are stuck on the question in some way.

```
class Person{ //Can't change from here.
public:
    Person(string n, int year) : name(n), yearOfBirth(year){}
    string getName();
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const Person&);
private:
    string name; int yearOfBirth;
}; // to here.

string Person::getName() //output the name
{
    // I think the output should be here but it doesn't work.
    // I have also switched the code in the operator into the getName put it still doesn't work.
    return name;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Person& P){ //turns everything into lowercase.
    locale loc;
    string temp = ""; //well be asigning the lowercase letters here; one at a time.
    int ii = 0;
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < P.name.length(); i++) { //reads the input one at a time.
        if ((ii == 0) || (ii >= 1 && ((P.name[i - 1]) == char(32)))) {(toupper(P.name[i], loc), (temp += toupper(P.name[i], loc))); }//if it was lowercase and the first letter, it turns it into uppercase and assigns it to temp.
        else (tolower(P.name[i], loc), (temp += tolower(P.name[i], loc))); //if it was uppercase it turns it into lowercase and assigns it to temp.
        ii++;
    } //name = temp; //assigns the full lowercase word back to input01.*/
    output << temp << " was born in " << P.yearOfBirth;
    return output;
}

int main(){
    Person::Person("lEonArDo DA vINCi", 1520);
    // I have tried putting a output statement here as well
    return 0;
}
```

So, my questions are; how should I output the name? (ie. cout.) and where would I need to put the output statement? (in getName or in the main function.) Even if you can just tell me a vague answer of where it should be will help me a lot. 
Sorry for having to ask a stupid question, and wasting your time.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to be more concise. All the information about your class, teacher, classmates, etc. is unnecessary.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for. `getName()` shouldn't be responsible for writing to an arbitrary `std::ostream` but just return what's stored as you're doing. The `operator<<()` implementation should access `getName()` rather than the member variable directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Person::Person("lEonArDo DA vINCi", 1520);
```

doesn't make a person. What you want is more along the lines of

```
Person leonardo("lEonArDo DA vINCi", 1520);
```

This makes a variable called `leonardo` of type `Person` and initializes it with `"lEonArDo DA vINCi", 1520`. `leonardo` can then be used to access this `Person`. For example, to get and print the name

```
std::cout << leonardo.getName() << std::endl;
```

Or, since you already have an << overload,

```
std::cout << leonardo <<std::endl;
```

to use the operator<< function.

You may want to move the capitalization rules from the << operator to the `Person` constructor. This way rather than storing the broken-cased "lEonArDo DA vINCi", you can store the correct version and print out only the correct version in the << operator. This makes the << operator much simpler and the correction only has to be run once on construction not every time you print.

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed that. Thank you so much. It was a very big help.